# Cassandra : Required RAM Space

Tags: cassandra

I have a two node Cassandra (3.10) cluster. I have migrated some data. Data size is 1.4 TB according to nodetool in each node. 
I tried to check RAM size required by Cassandra instance-

```
ps -aux | grep cassandra
```

I got :

```
root      2510  124 80.2 1515965216 26435808 pts/0 SLl 10:36 138:10 java -Xloggc:/opt/cassandra/logs/gc.log ...... /*/*.jar org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon
```

here we can see that Cassandra is taking nearly **26.5** GB space in RAM, and I observe that this size is continuously increasing.

I want to know is it a normal behavior of Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

So this is less a cassandra behavior and more a how java works. In your cassandra-env.sh file you can modify the starting and maximum memory values for cassandra.

`-Xms<Value>` Specifies how much memory cassandra starts with

`-Xmx<Value>` Specifies how much the heap size can grow until.

A common practice with cassandra is to initialize the process with `-Xms` and `-Xmx` being the same.  This removes the overhead of the server having to expand heapspace and allows it to be controlled so issues like what you're having don't occur.

As an aside, consider using G1GC instead of CMS for garbage collection if you're going to exceed 12GB.

Answer (score 0):

This site gives specifications for different packages and provides hardware requirements for all the types:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningHardware.html#planningHardware__memory

Take a look over it and find if its in range or not. You can even reduce and keep a limit on the size of RAM its occupying.